# Allowed memory size exhausted on category save Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, fatal-error, memory, magento-2.1.7

I'm trying to to enable the "Anchor" flag on a category with about 1400 products. When I click save, the page loads for a very long time (about 45 minutes) and finally gives me an internal server error 500.

I tried the same with a category with about 500 products, there it worked after about 20 minutes (still much too long but no error).

I get the following error in the php error log:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 33554440 bytes) in /Users/myuser/Sites/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3551

PHP settings:

```
memory_limit = 1024M  # in .user.ini
max_execution_time = 18000 # in .user.ini
post_max_size = 32M
max_input_vars = 100000
```

MySQL Settings:

```
max_allowed_packet = 1024M
wait_timeout = 180
```

Environment:

```
Installation: MAMP PRO
PHP-Version: 7.0.8.
```

Magento Settings:

- Version: 2.1.7
- All indexes are set to "UPDATE BY SCHEDULE" and were run
- Use flat category: YES (also tried with NO)
- Use flat product: YES (also tried with NO)
- Caches are cleared
- Tried clearing /var/generation folder

So basically, I tried everything I could find on the internet but nothing seemed to help. Of course I can now try to set memory_limit to 2056 but then it needs like 2 hours -  I don't think that's a solution.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the memory_limit from php.ini into as memory_limit = 536870912

Answer (score -1):

The issue is related to the new way of URL rewrites generator in Magento2. In Magento2, URL rewrites are generated (in url_rewrite table) when user save the category. If you have a complex category structure and assign a category as child of multiple parents or using categories across different store_views , it tries to generate the URL for all combinations and hence get out of memory.

Here are some links I'd recommend you to go through so you might found a solution for your problem.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9706

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10242

***This is not a solution but a workaround.***

I had also face the same issue with after migrating a huge Magento1 site. Here is the hack down there that is not a solution but it can confirm the issue for you. Update the following core file for instance and then try to update the category name.

> M2\vendor\magento\module-catalog-url-rewrite\Observer\CategoryProcessUrlRewriteSavingObserver.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Observer;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlRewriteGenerator;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlPersistInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CategoryProcessUrlRewriteSavingObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /** @var CategoryUrlRewriteGenerator */
    protected $categoryUrlRewriteGenerator;

    /** @var UrlPersistInterface */
    protected $urlPersist;

    /** @var UrlRewriteHandler */
    protected $urlRewriteHandler;

    /**
     * @param CategoryUrlRewriteGenerator $categoryUrlRewriteGenerator
     * @param UrlPersistInterface $urlPersist
     * @param UrlRewriteHandler $urlRewriteHandler
     */
    public function __construct(
        CategoryUrlRewriteGenerator $categoryUrlRewriteGenerator,
        UrlPersistInterface $urlPersist,
        UrlRewriteHandler $urlRewriteHandler
    ) {
        $this->categoryUrlRewriteGenerator = $categoryUrlRewriteGenerator;
        $this->urlPersist = $urlPersist;
        $this->urlRewriteHandler = $urlPersist;
    }

    /**
     * Generate urls for UrlRewrite and save it in storage
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var Category $category */
        /* $category = $observer->getEvent()->getCategory();
        if ($category->getParentId() == Category::TREE_ROOT_ID) {
            return;
        }
        if ($category->dataHasChangedFor('url_key')
            || $category->dataHasChangedFor('is_anchor')
            || $category->getIsChangedProductList()
        ) {
            $urlRewrites = array_merge(
                $this->categoryUrlRewriteGenerator->generate($category),
                $this->urlRewriteHandler->generateProductUrlRewrites($category)
            );
            $this->urlPersist->replace($urlRewrites);
        } */
    }
}
```